# Making simple Qtip descriptor in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, qtip

I am rewriting a large chunk of Javascript into Typescript and I have the `jquery.d.ts` file, which lets me do ajax calls etc, however I need to make my own descriptor for Qtip.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
interface JQuery
{
   qtip(options:any);
}
```

However this doesn't work, just keeps telling me that the method qtip `doesnt exist on value of type JQuery`.

So am I missing something? as I call it like so:

```
$("#some-element").qtip({some: "options"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up this issue was down to the way I was building the project, I had 3 or 4 modules which were all interdependant. So the actual class which used this jquery extension reference was working fine. However when the subsequent files referenced the file without referencing the extension blew up but made it look like the problem was in the original file, not in the referencing file.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery.d.ts, the result of invoking `$` is named `JQuery`, not `Jquery`. The naming here is case-sensitive.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on my part while writing the question. I will update to reflect this.